# how do i make it switch to black or white like a dark mode and light mode?

Tags: html, css

hello so I'm in the process of making a website right now and need some help. you see, i made this very cool switch link to see the switch= (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1613Pz0WJbdzKdyQWRQ-JUE2Kj--yoDIK/view?usp=sharing) (may have to download it) and I would like to know how I can make it change the background of the website. so when you flip it it turns black flip it again it turns white. can anyone help?

Comment: Plz include the respective HTML/CSS/JS.

Comment: You probably need to create a button that once the user clicks on it, it will add a class to the <body> and from there you change your CSS styles or CSS source.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS variables and a little bit of JavaScript to switch themes.

Define the theming in the `.light` or the `.dark` then set the class of the body to it.  It will set the variables to the theme color.

Ex:

```js
function toLight() {
  document.body.classList.remove('dark');
  document.body.classList.add('light');
}

function toDark() {
  document.body.classList.remove('light');
  document.body.classList.add('dark');
}
```

```css
.light {
  --font-color: #111;
  --bg-color: #fff;
}

.dark {
  --font-color: #eee;
  --bg-color: #111;
}

p, h1 {
  color: var(--font-color);
}

body {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

```html
<body class="light">
  <h1>title</h1>
  <p>text blah blah</p>
  
  <button onclick="toDark()">switch to dark</button>
  <button onclick="toLight()">switch to light</button>
</body>
```

Comment: so i could litteraly copy and paste that?

Comment: you'll need to add some CSS to style the elements for light and dark mode (with variables) and add some logic for the toggle button.  But for the rest, I think it'll work.

Comment: i dont know how to do that. could you tell me?

Comment: i dont know how to do that. could you show me?